# Adding namespace to C++ answer in an edit

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer

I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/236803/8) and was <strike>furious</strike>curious about the addition of the namespace.

I was thinking about immediately rolling the change back, but then, it's only a minor issue. Yet it bugs me enough to open a meta question.

Should I move on or would it be sensible to revert the edit?

Comment: It may be relevant that that answer is Community Wiki.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Indeed, I spent some time trying to find the people approving the edit ... .

Comment: Editing to improve readability is a widely accepted practice.  What subset of the language each [c++] programmer considers "evil" is his own choice, nobody will ever agree.

Comment: As much as I dislike using `using namespace std;` this edit does not appear to harm the code at all or change any of it meaning.  It also got rid of the horizontal scrolling so there is that to consider as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the horizontal scrolling is a good reason. Personally, I would never edit an answer just to add or remove std:: and readability in this case is subjective. I'll move on.